# Molpay recurring payment in WordPress

Tags: plugins

I am working now WordPress molpay recurring payment. My code is there. I have a recurring payment file. So still I am followed that file. But I don't know how may I fix this issue. Please help me.

```
$c_cost=isset($_REQUEST['m_cost']) ? $_REQUEST['m_cost'] : '0';

    $c_pay=$_REQUEST['payment'];

    $c_name=$_REQUEST['m_c_name'];

    $c_num=$_REQUEST['m_cred_num'];

    $c_date=$_REQUEST['m_exp_date'];

    $c_cvv=$_REQUEST['m_c_vv'];





    if(isset($_REQUEST['payment']) and $_REQUEST['payment'] != 'others')
    {

    $amount = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM bootsgrid_mol_payment where `id`=".$c_pay);

    $molpay_camount=$amount[0]->money;
    $c_month = $amount[0]->month;
    }

    else
    {
    $molpay_camount=$c_cost;
    $c_month = 0;
    }




    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    $table_name = "bootsgrid_mol_new_paynow";


    $wpdb->insert($table_name, array('user_id' =>$user_id, 'cost' => $c_cost,'payment' => $c_pay ,'credit_name' =>$c_name,'creditcard' =>$c_num,'ex_date'=>$c_date,'cvv'=>$c_cvv,'month'=>$c_month,'recurring_money'=>$molpay_camount,'created'=>time()));

    //order_id
    $last_id = $wpdb->insert_id;

    //merchant id and verfig key
    $bg_set = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM bootsgrid_molpay_setting" );
    $c_merchant_id=$bg_set[0]->merchant_id;
    $c_api_key=$bg_set[0]->verify_key;

    //amount
    $cdecimal_amount= number_format((float)$molpay_camount, 2, '.', '');



    //formula
    $Checksum = md5('T'.$c_merchant_id.$c_num.$last_id.'MYR'.$cdecimal_amount.$c_api_key );


    $recurring_array =array('T|'.$c_merchant_id.'||'.$c_num.'|'.$last_id.'|MYR|'.$cdecimal_amount.'|'.$Checksum);



    $URL ="https://www.onlinepayment.com.my/MOLPay/API/Recurring/input.php";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST , TRUE );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS , http_build_query($recurring_array));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , $URL );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , TRUE );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT , TRUE );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , TRUE );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , FALSE);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    print_r($result);exit;
```

I got a response

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Sat, 28 Jan 2017 05:01:14 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dc32c2870dfdd6f7bb177cd46f17be2f11485579673; expires=Sun, 28-Jan-18 05:01:13 GMT; path=/; domain=.onlinepayment.com.my; HttpOnly
    Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    Cache-Control: max-age=600
    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
    Server: cloudflare-nginx
    CF-RAY: 3281e2a02e832fdb-MAA

    [{"status":"failed","orderid":"69","tranID":"","reason":"Invalid token"}]
```

How can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the result and my Bootsgrid molpay recurring wordpress plugin here :
https://bootsgrid.com/product/recurring-molpay-plugin-wordpress/